# Yum results in centos are incomplete?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, dns, centos, fedora

I have recently installed the centos and i have updated and upgraded the packages and all went pretty good.Now the real problem is whenever i use `yum` the default package manager to search the reults it is showing is very small.

Even when i search for the virtualbox it is just showing only 2 results and the main virtutal box result which i want is not even there.

I even changed my dns in resol.conf file and the same problem persists.

I just attaching the log file here.

```
[root@localhost etc]# yum search virtualbox
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
======================== Matched: virtualbox =========================
freerdp.x86_64 : Remote Desktop Protocol client
virt-what.x86_64 : Detect if we are running in a virtual machine
```

How to resolv this problem and to list all the repository.
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p4Kn.jpg)

Just tried installing VirtualBox from rpm and it still produced the error as shown

```
[googlebot@localhost ~]$ cd Downloads/
[googlebot@localhost Downloads]$ ls
VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64.rpm
[googlebot@localhost Downloads]$ rpm -i V
error: open of V failed: No such file or directory
[googlebot@localhost Downloads]$ rpm -i VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64.rpm 
warning: VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 98ab5139: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libQt5Core.so.5()(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5Core.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5Core.so.5(Qt_5.6)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5Gui.so.5()(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5Gui.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5()(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5()(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5Widgets.so.5()(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5Widgets.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5X11Extras.so.5()(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libQt5X11Extras.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libpng16.so.16()(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libpng16.so.16(PNG16_0)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
    libvpx.so.3()(64bit) is needed by VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `virtualbox` in the official CentOS repository, [nor in EPEL](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/rpms/virtualbox/). If you want to have `virtualbox`. you will have to install additional repositories that provide this proprietary tools.

Define what else you consider "incomplete".

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the `EPEL` repo package. This repository provides a lot of additional packages, along with updates of the original ones.

To install it simply run:

```
yum install epel-release
```

Afterwards, your index will be populated with lots of additional packages that the original CentOS repos miss.

Comment: Just did the install still the search result is incomplete

Comment: ```
[googlebot@localhost ~]$ yum search virtualbox
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * epel: epel.mirror.net.in
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
======================== Matched: virtualbox =========================
freerdp.x86_64 : Remote Desktop Protocol client
kBuild.x86_64 : A cross-platform build environment
virt-what.x86_64 : Detect if we are running in a virtual machine
[googlebot@localhost ~]$ 

```

Comment: To install VirtualBox on CentOS you have to add their repo manually. Have a look at: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/rhel/virtualbox.repo